# Does anyone know if this particular letter D is available in a vector file format anywhere?

Tags: fonts, images

Hey everyone I've seen this letter and now I can't remember where and how it was, or just an image or animated-kind of font, I need this image hi-res or the vector file of this, or somethnig close to it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a reverse Google image search? It allows you to upload an image and finds possible locations of the file or similar ones.

Comment: Yes i did, unfortunately was just a bunch of golden color results...I came here only after few hours of search :)

Comment: @Scott - as a `font-idenfication` apologist, I'll stick up for this one since the concept is at least somewhat similar. Some people don't get search terms like 'drop cap' or 'gold filigree' in their head when they see something like this.

Comment: Hope you can work on with pen tool or magic wand tool and take it out as a vector. Very simplest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please be aware that this question is not in the scope defined by the community of Graphics Design Stack Exchange.

I did not find your particular vector online, but a stylized vector version is easily created in Inkscape using the "trace bitmap" feature, selecting the *colors* option, and clicking okay. [Vector copy of ornate letter](http://www.filetolink.com/604c442dfb)

If you want to render it at higher resolutions with this vector, you should blur it along the edges and along the faces of the letter, preferably with a filter effect to avoid the stylized appearance.  Otherwise, you could try modifying the vector or finding a different one.